# Неправильное позиционирование в HTML

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Недавно принялся изучать WEB, поэтому полно ошибок, и вот одна из них, которая возникает по непонятной мне причине.
В чём может быть проблема?

[image: Вот, что получается]

```css
body {
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

#go_to_another_page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    padding: 30px auto;
    border: 5px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(162, 162, 162);
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border: 5px solid rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

u {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}

a {
    font-family: monospace;
    color: pink; 
}

#Counter_ID {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <title>Заглавная страница</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "HomePageStyle.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p id = Counter_ID>Количество пользователей: 0</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уважаемый, откуда берутся эти пробелы вокруг знака "равно" в атрибутах тегов?  `<p id = Counter_ID>` - что это? Правильно так: `<p id="Counter_ID">`

Comment: Ну, это же не мешает браузеру читать документ и выводить информацию?

Comment: мешает, мягко говоря, псевдокод. Где остальное? Зачем столько стилей, если всего один элемент на странице? И что должно получиться - надпись по центру экрана?

Comment: Остальное убрал,потому-что в вопросе имеет смысл только этот элемент. А расположение элемента - внизу слева.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Если используете `position: absolute`, то нужно задавать чему-то и `position: relative` (в данном случае, это `<body>`).
- Если блокам не задавать размеры, то они либо растягиваются, либо схлопываются. А так, как Вы, по сути, изымаете из потока параграф, используя абсолютное позиционирование, то пустой `<body>` без размеров - схлопывается по высоте. Далее, параграф пытается найти `bottom` нижний край своего родителя (`<body>`), а он находится там же, где и `top` - вверху, потому что схлопнулся. Поэтому явно задаём размеры, если `<body>` пустой.
- Ну и конфликт стилей. А, вернее - задаёте новые свойства, не обращая внимания на уже существующие. Внимательно посмотрите на изменения в коде ниже.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(162, 162, 162);
}

#Counter_ID {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transform: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}


/*
#go_to_another_page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 30px auto;
  border: 5px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  border: 5px solid rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

u {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}

a {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: pink;
}
*/
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Заглавная страница</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="HomePageStyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p id="Counter_ID">Количество пользователей: 0</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае к абзацу применяются и стили описанные для селектора `p` и стили описанных для селектора `#Counter_ID`

В итоге расположение элементу задается с помощью следующих свойств:

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
```

Причем `left: 0` перебивает `left: 50%` так как класс описан позже.

Исходя из этих значений и располагается элемент:

1. верх элемента на уровне 50%
2. низ элемента в нуле
3. слева 0
4. и все это сдвинуто влево-вверх на половину самого элемента.

если необходимо было разместить элемент слева внизу, необходимо было сбросить значения `transform` и `top`

```css
body {
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(162, 162, 162);
}

#Counter_ID {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  
  top: auto;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<p id="Counter_ID">Количество пользователей: 0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

margin попробуй убрать у body.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `<p>` взять в одельный `<div>`. А лучше воспользуйтесь меню разработчика. В Chrome это правый щелчок и нажать "Просмотреть код". Там все будет видно где у вас ошибка